# Can you have a setup with both VPN over Tor and Tor over VPN

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, security, vpn, encryption

Is it possible to first connect to a VPN (like NordVPN or another VPN which supports VPN over Tor) that is preconfigured for Tor and then connect  to a VPN once you are browsing in Tor to encrypt both the exit and guard nodes? I've heard many people debate over whether Tor over VPN or VPN over Tor is better, but could you if you for some reason wanted to, do both at the same time? If so, what would the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: The answer to all of these VPN and Tor questions is "it depends". At best you'll make it slightly harder to track you, and at worst you'll make it trivial to de-anonymize you.

Comment: @Steve, but is it possible to have such a setup?

Comment: In theory yes as long as the VPN is using TCP, but I don't know about NordVPN specifically.

Comment: @Steve, but I mean there aren't a lot of VPNs that support Tor over VPN, so I wasn't sure though if you could use the setup mentioned in the question, since that hasn't really been tried before.